# Integrating jira cloud with self hosted gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab, jira

**Problem:**
Failed to update the gitlab instance for self-managed instances error while trying to integrate jira cloud with self-hosted version of gitlab using the 'Gitlab for Jira' app on the jira cloud.

**Context:**
I have a self hosted version of gitlab running on docker on Ubuntu (Windows WSL). I have opened the firewall for atlassian ip addresses for inbound traffic on Windows 10. I have also covered all the configurations specified on the gitlab pre-requisite page [https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira/connect-app.html#failed-to-update-the-gitlab-instance-for-self-managed-instances]

However, despite all these configurations, I am still presented with 'Failed to update the gitlab instance' error.

[image: Gitlab-selfhosted integration with Jira Cloud]

I would greatly appreciate if someone is able to point me in the right direction for this issue.

**Update 07.06.2023**
I ensured that the following steps have been addressed.

1. Allowing atlassian servers in my windows defender firewall inbound rules.
2. Using the ZeroSSL certificate in my gitlab-nginx configuration (gitlab-http.conf) [/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/]
3. Buying a domain and routing the traffic through that domain.
4. Specifying the accurate external_url in gitlab.rb configuration file.

Now, when I specify the new url I still get the same 'Failed to update the GitLab instance' error.

My only speculation as of now would be that the SSL certificate issued might not be very well formed as the ZeroSSL console fails to detect the same despite the certificate being present.

[image: ZeroSSL Certificate Verification]

Following is the outcome now after the above steps:-

[image]